# Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'hashValue'

Tags: swift, xcode, anyobject

i am using this [LocationPicker](https://github.com/ZhuoranTan/LocationPicker) in my project and when i build the project the library has an error saying this: `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'hashValue'` so i opened the code and i found the error line here the code:

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let object = object else { return false }
        return (object as AnyObject).hashValue == hashValue
    }
```

i am new to swift and i am thinking maybe theres another syntax for the above code i am using a newer version of swift `5.0` and `xcode10`.

i tried using the autofix feature xcode suggests but doesnt work.

Comment: It’s a known issue https://github.com/zhuorantan/LocationPicker/issues/42

Comment: And again https://github.com/zhuorantan/LocationPicker/issues/44

Comment: And see https://github.com/zhuorantan/LocationPicker/pull/43

Answer (score -1):

AnyObject not follow Hashable protocol

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let object = object else { return false }

    if let object = object as? Hashable {
        return object.hashValue == hashValue
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```